# Rails Deployment to AWS ElasticBeanstalk/RDS failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying out ElasticBeanstalk on AWS for the first time and managed to get my to app environment to display on the AWS console, but deployment fails. My app is connected to a Postgres RDS instance.

The logs tell me that the deployment is failing as a result of the app's hstore requirement. I am installing this extension if it does not exist.

In my application, I have this script setup as a rake task:

```
# lib/tasks/db_enhancements.rake

####### Important information ####################
# This file is used to setup a shared extensions #
# within a dedicated schema. This gives us the   #
# advantage of only needing to enable extensions #
# in one place.                                  #
#                                                #
# This task should be run AFTER db:create but    #
# BEFORE db:migrate.                             #
##################################################


namespace :db do
  desc 'Also create shared_extensions Schema'
  task :extensions => :environment  do
    # Create Schema
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;'
    # Enable triagram
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Hstore
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS HSTORE SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:create"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end

Rake::Task["db:test:purge"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end
```

I also make sure to include the postgres extension in my ebextensions config:

```
# .ebextensions/packages.config
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql93-devel: []
```

The first error presented in the Deployment log is this:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
```

Could anybody help guide me to see what I'm doing incorrectly please?

*PS. I am using the EB CLI

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem, and I can solve with next steps:

**Identify your VpcSecurityGroupId**

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier <DBInstanceIdentifier>
sg-xxxxxxxxx
```

**Edit your SecurityGroup**
Now go to AWS Console / **VCP** / **Security Groups** and search with your VpcSecurityGroupId
In Inbound Rules add other rule with Type:All TCP, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: ALL, and Source:
0.0.0.0/0
**Connect to RDS Console**

With your end point use this

```
psql --host=xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=dbxxxxx --dbname=ebxxx
```

Write Password for user dbxxxxx, and

```
ebdb=>  CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

And this is all. :)